# Have I ruined my new vacuum cleaner?

Tags: vacuum

I have a new vacuum cleaner. This is the second time I have used it. I was vacuuming up some caulking residue. It was not fully dry and the heat from the vacuum melted it further as it was being sucked into the tube. I looked inside the tube and I could see some caulking stuck to the sides. Can this be bad?

Thank you

Comment: yes it is bad.... clean what you can

Comment: A lot of the building dust is not good for it. If its still working, then you are in luck. But try to clean it. The hose should be detachable, cleant it well. And clean what you can, looking into the body.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete disaster, a few house hold products may help, vinegar, alcohol, and WD-40, failing that you may need to flush it with industrial-grade isopropyl alcohol, don't worry about the actual machine itself, the machine has filters to protect it. Most you will require is a new tube.

Comment: None of those products will shift some types of caulk.  And you might need new filters as well as a new hose (or even instead) but they're replaceable too